# Show that the center of the sphere lies on the line $z=0,x^2+y^2=(a^2-c^2)\csc^22\alpha$

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

> A variable sphere passes through the points $(0,0,\pm c)$ and cuts the
>   lines $y=x\tan\alpha$, $z=c$; $y=-x\tan\alpha$, $z=-c$ in the points $P,P'$. If
>   $PP'$ has constant length $2a$ show that the center of the sphere lies
>   on the line $z=0$, $x^2+y^2=(a^2-c^2)\csc^22\alpha$.

The variable sphere is passing through $(0,0,c),(0,0,-c),(x_1,x_1\tan\alpha,c),(x_1,-x_1\tan\alpha,-c)$.

Let the center of the sphere be $(X,Y,Z)$.

So $X^2+Y^2+(Z-c)^2=X^2+Y^2+(Z+c)^2=(X-x_1)^2+(Y-x_1\tan\alpha)^2+(Z-c)^2=(X-x_1)^2+(Y+x_1\tan\alpha)^2+(Z+c)^2$

Solving $X^2+Y^2+(Z-c)^2=X^2+Y^2+(Z+c)^2$
I get $Z=0$ but I am not able to get $X^2+Y^2=(a^2-c^2)\csc^22\alpha$.

Please help.

Comment: A sphere is characterized by origin and radius. What is variable here?

Comment: I wonder as well what one should do with the four intersection points. It looks like it will intersect with $(0,0,\pm c)$ at some times $t_+$ and $t_-$. But what does this help, if there is no model for origin $r(t)$ and radius $R(t)$?

Comment: Then the two lines. They are separated by $2c$ in $z$-direction and otherwise look like some cross with opening angle dependent on $\alpha$ from above. Attaching a segment of length $2a$ between both lines should not  work if $a < c$.